# Double hashing scheme on not collision resistant hash

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-256, birthday-attack

Given an hash H that is not collision resistant, for example 80-bit digest, if we use the following double hashing scheme: H(SHA2-256(x)).

Does this scheme increase the collision resistance?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this scheme increase the collision resistance?

No (at least, not if we assume that $H$ is not collision resistant because of the limited output size); the standard birthday attack (where you compute $2^{40}$ hashes, and look for a common value) still works.  The only thing the initial SHA-256 does is make evaluating the hash a bit more expensive - it doesn't frustrate the attack in any other way.

And, in case you're wondering, we know how to search for such a collision without a memory that can store $2^{40}$ hashes...

Comment: I agree, what about inverting the scheme?
For example SHA2-256(H(x))? I think that even in this case the attack simply consist in attacking the first hash with the birthday attack, so it's again 2^40 hashes.

Comment: @N-K: you are correct; narrowing things anywhere to 80 bits allows a collision attack...

Comment: It doesn't even *necessarily* make the evaluation more expensive. If H is expensive to evaluate, it could be cheaper to evaluate SHA-256 on a long input and H only on the short hash.

Comment: I'd suggest "Not necessarily" where there is "No", because for some $H$ the answer is yes; e.g. for SHA-1 or MD5 the question's "scheme increases the collision resistance" by a factor over 1000.

Comment: SHA-256(“80 bit hash”) is an 80 bit hash.